Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[a,b]$ and $\mathbb R$.
Let $\mathfrak B_{[a,b]}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some non degenerate interval $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb R$. Let $\mathfrak B_{\mathbb R}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R$. We want to show that $\mathfrak B_{[a,b]} \subseteq \mathfrak B_{\mathbb R}$. I thought of showing that $\mathcal T_{[a,b]}$ (where $\mathcal T_{[a,b]}$ is the set of open sets in the metric space $([a,b],d)$) is contained in $B_{\mathbb R}$ which would thus imply that $\mathfrak B_{[a,b]} \subseteq \mathfrak B_{\mathbb R}$ by minimality. But a peer told me that the two sets are different and you can't compare them? I don't see anything wrong with this though. Indeed, every set in  $\mathcal T_{[a,b]}$ is of the form $[a,b] \cap U$ for some open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$.

This is correct. Every subset of $[a,b]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so you can ask if it is an element in $\mathfrak{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$, there is nothing wrong with that.

I think that what they are trying to say is that $\mathcal B_{[a, b]}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R$ and therefore you cannot say that one is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the other. Moreover, one is a subset of $2^{[a,b]}$ and the other is a subset of $2^\mathbb R$.

I thought of showing that $\mathcal T[a,b]$ (where $\mathcal T[a,b]$ is the set of open sets in the metric space $([a,b],d)$) is contained in $\mathcal B_\mathbb R$ which would thus imply that $\mathcal B[a,b]⊆\mathcal B_\mathbb R$ by minimality.

Like I said, you cannot use this minimality argument because they are not $\sigma$-algebras in the same space. Even though there is a relationship between the generators, because they are in different spaces, the $\sigma$-algebras generated by them can be not related. Take, for instance, the sets $A=\{1, 2\}$ and $B=\mathbb N$. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\{1\}\}$ in $A$ is not a subset of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\{1\},\{3\}\}$ in $B$, even tough one is contained in the other.
In your particular case, the inclusion will be true (looking at these two $\sigma$-algebras as subsets of $2^\mathbb R$). For more details see Folland's book Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications in the Notes and References of Chapter 1.
